# sails cannot lift when changing adapter to sails-disk or sails-memory

Tags: sails.js

I would like to use sails with sails-disk, migrate: drop so that whenever I run testcase I can have a new database with the following configuration on local.js. I am fine with sails lift. However, once I update migrate: drop or adapter to sails-disk or sails-memory. I am not able to sails lift from bootstrap and under server I can not even get configuration information. the sails lift just handling. without any detail message.

```
#config.js
    module.exports = {

  models: {
    connection: 'testing',
    migrate: 'drop',
  },

  connections: {
    testing: {
      adapter: 'sails-disk',
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      user: 'test',
      password: 'test',
      database: 'db',
    },
  },
};
#bootstrap.test.js

const TestConfig = require('./config/local');

before((done) => {
  // Increase the Mocha timeout so that Sails has enough time to lift.
  Sails.lift({
    connections: TestConfig.connections,
    models: TestConfig.models,
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }

      return done(err, server);
    });
});

#error message
after adding more debug information before return I can not get config information

    1) "before all" hook

0 passing (3s)
1 failing

1)  "before all" hook:
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
    at async.series (test/bootstrap.test.js:29:26)
    at node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3888:9
    at node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
    at replenish (node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1006:25)
    at node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1016:9
    at eachOfLimit (node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1041:24)
    at node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1046:16
    at _parallel (node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3879:5)
    at Object.series (node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4735:5)
    at Sails.lift (test/bootstrap.test.js:19:11)
```

Comment: Well you could look (or paste here) what is on that `test/bootstrap.test.js:29:26` - why the 'config' is calling for the undefined.

Comment: thank you. it turns out it may be sails version issue. after I downgrade from sails v1.0.2 to v.0.12.7 without change anyline of code. it is fine now

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am also trying to get the database to be same as when just lifted before each test suite.

Comment: yes.. i turn out something wrong with my local version. so I clean up everything and debug step by step then it is fine for me though

Comment: @jacobcan118 may you please share your code, I am struggling mightily to make my tests work on a seperate database, that is cleaned before each test - https://stackoverflow.com/q/53638665/1828637

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not providing any error message, I just can guessing that your config is wrong.
You have to name each connection and tell which one you want to use.

```
module.exports = {
  models: {
    migrate: 'drop',
    connection : 'testing',
  },
  connections: {
    testing : {
      adapter: 'sails-disk',
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      user: 'user',
      password: 'password',
      database: 'db',
   }
 },
},
```

Comment: thank you.. that is what I did actually..i update more detail in description