# Mocha tests, clean disk database before every file runs

Tags: unit-testing, testing, sails.js, integration-testing

I am using Sails 1.x.

Is it possible to reset the Sails.js database before each test file runs? I want it to be in state after `sails.lift()` completes before each run. I followed the docs here - https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/testing - but did not end up with any solution like this.

The only solution I'm having right now is to change the `lifecyle.test.js` `before` and `after` to run `beforeEvery` and `afterEvery` - https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/testing - so this is lifting everytime before test. But it takes a long time to lift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple to do. You just need to specify to add test connection in your connections on datasourses (depends on the version of Sails.js), setup it as active during the test and provide migration strategy `'drop'` which is just rebuild your DB every time on startup

```
models: {
    connection: 'test',
    migrate: 'drop'
},
```

My connections Sails.js 0.12.14

```
module.exports.connections = {
  prod: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    database: 'some-db'
  },

  test: {
    adapter: 'sails-memory'
  },
};
```

My simplified lifecycle.test.js

```
let app;
// Before running any tests...
before(function(done) {
    // Lift Sails and start the server
    const Sails = require('sails').constructor;

    const sailsApp = new Sails();
    sailsApp.lift({
        models: {
            connection: 'test',
            migrate: 'drop'
        },
    }, function(err, sails) {
        app = sails;
        return done(err, sails);
    });
});

// After all tests have finished...
after(async function() {
    // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
    // (e.g. you might want to destroy the records you created above)

    try {
        await app.lower()
    } catch (err) {
        await app.lower()
    }
});
```

In Sails 1 it's even simpler

```
const sails = require('sails');

before((done) => {
  sails.lift({
    datastores: {
      default: {
        adapter: 'sails-memory'
      },
    },
    hooks: { grunt: false },
    models: {
      migrate: 'drop'
    },
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) { return done(err); }

    return done();
  });
});

after(async () => {

  await sails.lower();

});
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for the attention. I don't understand though, are you lifting and lowering before/after each test. Is this not excessive?

Comment: Do you also know how to use Cloud SDK in tests? Me and another user is having this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/q/53462491/1828637

Comment: @Noitidart frankly speaking I haven't worked with Cloud SDK directly, but my colleague uses it. You definitely should do it via custom build steps https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps I guess it will look like http://prntscr.com/ls8o93

Comment: @Noitidart [here is](https://hub.packtpub.com/how-add-unit-tests-sails-framework-application/) also basics of Sails.js unit testing, but it is for Sails.js 0.12.14-

Comment: Thanks very much. I will be watching your TDD question closely I also want to do same and will share with you if I figure stuff out. In your solution above, should the answer be to change `before` to `beforeEvery`? and `after` to `afterEvery`?

Comment: Also @Pavlo - Ration test seems to use Cloud - if we first create at `test` direction, then run `sails run rebuild-cloud-sdk`, it creates `private/CLOUD_SDK_METHODS.json` in the `test/` directory. Then after that I copied and pasted this - https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/blob/master/test/private/before.js - but it resulted in error here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/53637743/1828637 - juuuust in case if this helps you to help me haha. I think TDD is super important.

Comment: @Noitidart about `before` to `beforeEvery`, actually it is called `beforeEach` in [official docs](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) and I don't think that we should change it, cause we don't need to reliift our app each time, cause it will take extra 500 ms while unit test should be fast and we will be much more limited during testing CRUD when we when we can run all this operation tests in consequent tests. This just my IMHO so maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Pavlo. The reason I want to re-lift is because for each unit test i need any persisted data to be reset to as if it were just lifted, is that possible any other way? Or is lowering/re-lifting the only way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this in my bootstrap test file to make the database clean.

```
const sails = require('sails');

before((done) => {
  sails.lift({
    log: {
      level: 'silent'
    },
    datastores: {
      default: {
        adapter: 'sails-disk',
        inMemoryOnly: true
      }
    },
    models: {
      migrate: 'drop',
      archiveModelIdentity: false
    }
  }, function (err, sails) {
    if (err) return done(err);
      done(err, sails);
  });
});

after(async () => {
  await sails.lower();
});

beforeEach((done) => {
  sails.once('hook:orm:reloaded', done);
  sails.emit('hook:orm:reload');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing Anh! Lifting after every test suite takes a long time though right? I ended up just manually cleaning up all the data by calling `MODEL.destroy({});` for each model.

Comment: In terms of run time, it's not noticeable for me by lifting every test suite (maybe my tests are not big enough?).

Comment: My lift takes 30 seconds.